# Titanium - How to use svg files for fontawesome?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using this widget [com.mattmcfarland.fontawesome](https://github.com/MattMcFarland/com.mattmcfarland.fontawesome) for fontawesome, but I need to use my Svg files. It's possible by using this widget, or there is other way? and how ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

There is Ti.SVGView (https://github.com/caffeinalab/Ti.SvgView) and an example at https://github.com/icecandy/TitaniumRenderSVGIconsExample on how to use it. But you need to fork and recompile it if you want to use it with Ti 7.

With the fontawesome Widget you can just use the font. The widget only translates the names to the utf codes, so you don't really need it when you type the codes (e.g. `\uf104`) into the `label.text` property.

**Solution 2:**

You can translate your SVG into a font with e.g. https://icomoon.io/app/ and use it as a normal font. The you just set the font-family to this font and use the codes you asign in icomoon to display your icons